# Run a cron job hourly in a set window

Tags: cron

My crontab file looks like this:

```
00 07-22 * * * /usr/bin/php /ab/c.php
```

but rather than running from 7am to 10pm, it runs at midnight as well. I want it strictly run every hour between 7 am to 10 pm.

Comment: Your format looks OK. Is the time on your system set to your local time?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the leading 0s? They can cause you problems. Try

```
0 7-22 * * * /usr/bin/php /ab/c.php
```

Besides the 0s which sound strange to me (I never used them), the rest seems ok. Hope this help.

Comment: let me try out and get back to you